# Set custom .properties file in gradle for liquibase update task

Tags: gradle, liquibase

I use this task for liquibase update:

```
task liquibaseUpdate(type: JavaExec) {
    description 'Liquibase updates DB by all not used changesets'
    group = 'Liquibase'
    classpath configurations.liquibase
    main = 'liquibase.integration.commandline.Main'
    if ( 
        project.hasProperty("username") &&
        project.hasProperty("password") &&
        project.hasProperty("url")
    ) {
        Map<String,?> propertyMap = project.getProperties()
        args "--username=${propertyMap['username']}"
        args "--password=${propertyMap['password']}"
        args "--url=${propertyMap['url']}"
    }
    args 'update'
}
```

It loads settings from `liquibase.properties` file. How can I use custom properties file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably `--defaultsFile=</path/to/file>` switch is what you're looking for. Please have a look [here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html#using_a_liquibase.properties_file).